# How to zoom in iOS Simulator more than 100%?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I'm working on my project and use Xcode iOS simulator.
I want to zoom in more than 100% for iPhone 5/5s screen size, but the maximum is just 100%. I use retina display 13'' Macbook, so I can't see every details what is going on the screen. 
Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't zoom more than 100%.

One idea if you wanna see some deeper details of one specific UI you can take a screen shot of the 100% zoomed screen by pressing/going to

**command + s** or **File > Save Screen Shot**

and then Zoom it as deep as you want.

Answer (score 4):

There's 4 stages of zoom by pressing cmd + 1,2,3,4 that's all you can do for zooming with only simulator.

Comment: It's not exactly what I needed but it was helpful

Answer (score 4):

In case if `Window - Zoom` menu item is disabled for you, uncheck `Show Device Bezels`.

[image: iOS simulator zoom not working]

Answer (score -1):

Just take a screenshot and then zoom on it.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031825/2227743).